# Dropzone.js Don't Show Result After Upload

Tags: model-view-controller, upload, dropzone

Im trying to upload multiple files by dropzone.js in my MVC Project. The files upload successfully but the problem: after upload files, the page reset and i cant see the results. I have almost searched all the related subjects in this site and the other examples. I see people want to learn how they can refresh page :) but i want to stop page after upload. The results preview disappear quickly. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

After hours, i see its not about dropzone, its about mvc. Because of post data in mvc, if you save a file, modelstate change, then automatically redirect the previous action/view and the results disappear. So it seems like a page refresh. Anyway, its suggested to use PRG instead of POST. Or redirect another GET action after successfully upload.